# What is the performance implication of having lots of open files on Linux?

Tags: performance, file-io

Does anyone know the effect of having lots of open file descriptors on server performance? Like lets say I simultaneously open up 1000 files.

My operating system is Ubuntu 12.04 and I am running Intel.

Comment: Doing what with them? Doing what without them?

Comment: Do you mean performance implications of just keeping them open or implications of _using_ that many descriptors in some particular way?

Comment: I suppose I'd like to know both scenarios: 1) just open (effect of the open file descriptors) 2) doing a merge of the data in each of those file on the effect of a bystander process that may or may not necessarily be doing file io.

Comment: You can only open 1000 files using open.  If you use fopen, it stops at 254.

Comment: Disk cache size will matter a lot if there is much i/o being done. Configure your system accordingly. As for just open: you can try this with a simple program - it shouldn't have too much of an effect until after some initial open output (inode allocation) has been done.